# Can't find API documentation for basic object expression like vars, request, ctx in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've read the official documents but i cant find details object information like 
method, constructor, fields for basic message expression like *#vars*, *#request*, etc. Maybe i don't know how to find it

i just started to learn thyme leaf for spring boot and i wanna debug thyme leaf so i can figure out what variable that passed into view or html pages.

but i cant find the keyword to google it. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this in the documentation:

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#web-context-namespaces-for-requestsession-attributes-etc.

There also are the links to the JavaDoc. For example

```
/*
 * ============================================================================
 * See javadoc API for class org.thymeleaf.context.WebRequestParamsVariablesMap
 * ============================================================================
 */
```

Comment: thanks, didnt notice that before..